# How to cast IQueryable to IQueryable<T> when I don't know the T in advance?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, telerik

I have an asp.net mvc view, which is using Telerik's grid.

```
Html.Telerik.Grid(Model.Items)
```

Model.Items is IQueryable, but the Grid requires me to cast it:

For example:

```
Html.Telerik.Grid((IQueryable<Product>)Model.Items)
```

The problem is: I don't know what type is in Model.Items (it can be `IQueryable<Product>`, `IQueryable<Book>` and many others).

What I also have is Model.ItemsType, which can have following values: `typeof(IQueryable<Product>)`, `typeof(IQueryable<Book>)`...

How can I cast the IQueryable to `IQueryable<T>`, when I don't know the type of T in advance?

Answer (score 0):

Generic types need to be known at ***compile-time***, not determined at ***run-time***.

What is the type of `Model.Items`? If it's derived from `IEnumerable<T>` then assuming you have a reference to `System.Linq` then you should be able to call the `AsQueryable()` extension method.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use reflection to invoke the Grid method when you don't know the T ahead of time, because there's no way to do it at compile time. If Model.Items actually is an IQueryable, then you don't need to cast it; just pass it along as the parameter during the reflection-based invocation (which takes all parameters as type object anyway).

Comment: Thank you, Brad (I'm reading your blog and I watched your videos: p&p symposium and advanced mvc). I have found a solution and I'll post it here later (I'm busy now).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try binding to IEnumerable. Check the '[Binding to a collection of dynamic objects with MVC3 Razor](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-mvc/grid/binding-to-a-collection-of-dynamic-objects-with-mvc3-razor.aspx)' code library entry.